# How to print number with commas as thousands separators in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I got stacked in printing numbers that was separeted with commas

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import DataFrame,Series


d = {'Sex' : Series(["Male","Male","Female","Female","Female","Male","Female","Female","Male"]),
      'Rank' : Series(["A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C"]),
      'Num_x' : Series([1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,4000,5000,6000]),
    'Num_y' : Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
      'States' : Series(["Ohio","Ohio","Ohio","Ohio","Ohio","Ohio","Ohio","Ohio","Ohio"])}

DF = DataFrame(d)

plt.scatter(DF['Num_x'],DF['Num_y'])
```

thanks for reading

Answer (score 1):

You can prepare the string with something like:

```
"{:,.02f}".format(123456789.1234324)
```